# Making an SQLite ConnectionString portable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sqlite, portability

As a personal project I want to test the ability of using SQLite with MVC 3 and so far so good managed to get everything setup.

The thing I am now trying to achieve is to make the solution fully portable during development, but I am unable to achieve this as the connection string is complaining that the database is missing if I try on different machines where the solution it located in different places.

Is there any way that I can alter the connection string so it is uses a set directory each and everytime?

I have the database housed in a datalayer solution in the same folder houses my datamodel if that is any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

- Specify the location of the SQLite database as relative to the executable
- Make the path specifiable as input (say a command line argument or .config file)